# How to share a remote mounted folder using sshfs?

Tags: server, windows-7, sshfs

I used the sshfs app to mount a remote folder. The problem now is that I can't seem to share it. I can see all of it's contents when I directly do an ls and I also see it in the mount list when I run the mount command.

I mounted the folder on a folder I had shared (using samba) which I could see in my windows explorer (windows 7 64bit). I couldn't see the mounted folder after I mounted when I umount I can see it again.

I tried sharing the folder directly in the smb conf but it didn't do anything.

Can anyone help me out please?

EDIT:

I have done what JanC told me and I do see it know in the explorer window the only problem is I can't access it. It says I don't have permissions. Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

You must use the "allow_other" mount option for sshfs to make mounts visible to all users.  If that doesn't fix the problem, you should probably give the mount options you use.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked. I can see it in the windows explorer, but when I double click it it doesn't allow access. I have set in the smb.conf to allows guests but it still won't let me have access

Comment: You should probably check the ownership & permissions of the files you try to access...